# PHP die mysqli error

Tags: php, html

Sorry, I have trouble this scrip, die(mysqli_error()); , i try change to die(mysqli_error($koneksi)); ,but not solved. Thanks in advance

```
$insert = mysqli_query($koneksi, "INSERT INTO karyawan (nik, nama, tempat_lahir, tanggal_lahir, statusp, suis, janak, alamat, domisili, no_ktp, no_telepon, no_bpjs, no_bpjsk, no_rek, no_npwp, jabatan, status, username, password)
VALUES ('$nik','$nama', '$tempat_lahir', '$tanggal_lahir', '$statusp', '$suis', '$janak', '$alamat', '$domisili', '$no_ktp', '$no_telepon', '$no_bpjs', '$no_bpjsk', '$no_rek', '$no_npwp', '$jabatan', '$status', '$username', '$pass')") 
or die(mysqli_error())
```

Answer (score -1):

**First** of all note that [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) need link identifier as a ist param like:

```
mysqli_error($koneksi)
```

**Second**, you forgot to terminate your line, you must need to use semi colon for terminate this line.

**Third**, if you are getting blank page, than you must need to use php [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in your code in development mode not for production.

**Fourth**, Don't know where you define your variables, if its user input than note that your code is open for SQL injection. You can use [Prepared Statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) will help you to prevent your query with SQL Attack: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

*Side Note: explore provided links and modify your code, i hope this will help you.*